# Yeoman custom generator automatically install gulp + dependencies when creating new project

Tags: npm, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm brand new to Yeoman and even Gulp. I'm making websites that are very similar between them, so I'm trying to create a custom generator for Yeoman. I've managed to make template html files, and to copy over both files and folders when running the generator.

I made template package.json and gulpfile.js files with dependencies that all projects will be using, such as gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-autoprefixer, etc. My question now is: How do I make the generator automatically install npm and all dependencies when I run it in a new project? Or do I have to run `npm install --save-dev ***` for each dependency every time I create a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependencies in the `package.json` files inside your generator.

For example https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node/blob/master/generators/gulp/index.js#L42 (there's other way to do this too. It depends on your needs)

Then you just call `this.installDependencies()`.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Where exactly do I call `this.installDependencies`? I assume in the index.js file, but where and how?

Comment: Okay, never mind, I just wrote it like that at the end of my `writing:` function and it worked! Please let me know, though, if that is not optimal. Thanks again!

Comment: You can call it anywhere, it'll just schedule the installation to the end of the process no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke commands:

```
generator.spawnCommandSync("bower", ["install"]);
generator.spawnCommandSync("npm", ["install"]);
```

Comment: This wouldn't take into account the standard `--skip-install` flag of yeoman generators.